# How do I hide the title bar in Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I'd like to get rid of the (very out of place) white bar at the top of the editor without having to go fullscreen. How can I do this in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/chrome-less-sublime/1125/16.
Basically, you can use WinExp to remove the title bar:

> I used WinExplorer[1] to remove the border and the window title bar.

1. [Download WinExplorer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winexp.html)
2. Select Sublime Text 3 window(s)
3. Go to "Style" tab
4. Untick "WS_THICKFRAME" and "WS_DLGFRAME"

Comment: Welcome on Superuser. Please describe how to remove the top bar in Sublime 3 in conjunction with your link. The reason for this is simple, this link could become invalid. If you describe the steps required any future user could still use your answer even if that link is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it is so simple we can't see.
I have just started to search for a solution and realized that ...

**F11** - Enter Full Screen

... could get it done.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! That would hide the bar, but unfortunately OP specifically asked *"without having to go fullscreen"*

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't see that. You are correct. Thank you.
However, I don't like using third party softwares for such purposes.
I use to work on dual monitors and, on that scenario, I can set sublime to the secondary, with no Windows task bar and there is no problem using fullscreen. I really appreciate the result.